# i am trying to use tabhost and its creating problems

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I am trying to use the tabhost and it shows the following error:

> thread id=1 StackOverflow on call to landroid/util/sparsearray;binary search ILIII

Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.menu);
TabHost mytabhost;
mytabhost=getTabHost();
TabSpec homespec=mytabhost.newTabSpec("home");
homespec.setIndicator("Home",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
Intent homeintent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),menu.class);
homespec.setContent(homeintent);

TabSpec infospec=mytabhost.newTabSpec("info");
infospec.setIndicator("Info",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.info));
Intent infointent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),info.class);
infospec.setContent(infointent);

TabSpec servicespec=mytabhost.newTabSpec("Services");
servicespec.setIndicator("Services",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.services));
Intent serviceintent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),services.class);
servicespec.setContent(serviceintent);

TabSpec onlinespec=mytabhost.newTabSpec("onlinetools");
onlinespec.setIndicator("Onlinetools",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.onlinetools));
Intent onlineintent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),onlinetools.class);
onlinespec.setContent(onlineintent);

TabSpec mediaspec=mytabhost.newTabSpec("MediaCenter");
mediaspec.setIndicator("MediaCenter",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mediacenter));
Intent mediaintent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),mediacenter.class);
mediaspec.setContent(mediaintent);

mytabhost.addTab(homespec);
mytabhost.addTab(infospec);
mytabhost.addTab(servicespec);
mytabhost.addTab(onlinespec);
mytabhost.addTab(mediaspec);
```

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/util/SparseArray;.binarySearch:ILIII

Comment: method requires 36+20+0=56 bytes, fp is 0x4403e32c (44 left)

Comment: expanding stack end (0x4403e300 to 0x4403e000)

Comment: May this thread helps : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rowboat/lP65eylKHkQ/flHykmz15xAJ